# Names of variables repeated 2 or more times in a list of data.frames in R

Tags: r, list, function, loops, dataframe

Generally, in a `list` of `data.frame`s (for example below), I was wondering how I could obtain the names of the variables that are ***repeated 2 or more times*** (in this example the names would be `"AA"`, `"BB"`, `"CC"`) across the `data.frame`s?

```
r <- list( data.frame( AA = c(2,2,1,1,NA, NA), BB = c(1,1,1,2,2,NA), CC = c(1:5, NA)),

        data.frame( AA = c(1,NA,3,1,NA,NA), BB = c(1,1,1,2,NA,NA)),

        data.frame( AA = c(1,NA,3,1,NA,NA), BB = c(1,1,1,2,2,NA), CC = c(0:4, NA)) )
```

Comment: use `duplicated` over the vector of names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could:

1. `unlist` the list to get all column names as a single vector,
2. check for the (`unique`) duplicate names in the vector using `duplicated`.

```r
## get names
vec <- names(unlist(r, recursive = FALSE))

## return duplicates
unique(vec[duplicated(vec)])
#> [1] "AA" "BB" "CC"
```

Comment: A follow up, is it also possible to know **the number** of variables that are repeated 2 or more times (in the example above, my desired output is: `AA 3 times`, `BB 3 times`, `CC 2 times`)?

Comment: @rnorouzian: `table(vec)` gives the counts of each variable.